# A Safe Solution to the Max Macro?

Tags: c, macros

We all know this famous macro example:

```
#define max(a,b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

And, since it uses `a` and `b` twice, it becomes inaccurate when we do something like:

```
max(x, y++); // because this gets translated to...
((x) > (y++) ? (x) : (y++)); // y is incremented twice
```

In *Effective C++*, Scott Meyers presents a C++ solution to this, using `inline` functions.

In *21st Century C*, I was hoping for a similar C solution, but sadly all it advised was to avoid double usage. That made me sad. :'(

Of course, one can always replace it with a regular function. But I was wondering whether there is a C-only macro solution to this, that solves the double usage problem. **Any possible solution?**

Comment: Exactly why one should avoid macros whenever possible and not the opposite.

Comment: There was actually an interesting article on a C++ solution for this [here](http://www.drdobbs.com/generic-min-and-max-redivivus/184403774) if you're at all interested.

Comment: I don't have answer but, can't stop the expression: using increment/decrement operators in conditions is not my thing - I see that to be more of obscurity (towards human errors) than elegance or convenience in coding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In case of GCC you can use [typeof](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html) extension, like this:

```
#define max(a,b) \
    ({ typeof (a) _a = (a); \
        typeof (b) _b = (b); \
        _a > _b ? _a : _b; })
```

Comment: ... and typeof(x++) = (x++) will not increment x twice?

Comment: `typeof` parameter doesn't get evaluated

Answer (score 3):

To your relief C has `inline` functions since C99.

Comment: No, praise the C standards committee, they deserve it.

Comment: C11 also adds `_Generic`, which lets you dispatch a macro to different implementation functions based on argument type. ("overloading")